# What are some URL shorteners that use GET requests?

Tags: url-shortening

I've been writing a script that requires a link shortener in it. It runs locally, and Chrome can't use AJAX/JSON locally, so I need to be able to go to `link.shortener/link-to.shorten` and then it automatically shortens the link. Are there any web shorteners that work like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple:

- http://b54.in/api.php
- https://is.gd/apishorteningreference.php

Just remember that most of these services aren't monetised and tend to disappear, rendering the links useless. Of the 8 or so services that advertised using GET, these are the only two that still work.